# Possible values of probability for an unfair die

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

In a presumably unfair dice the unknown probabilities of appearance of the individual faces are respectively p1, ..., p6 (none of them are zeros).

Through repeated experiments it has been noted that the probability of
rolling a streak of 6 consecutive numbers (i.e. rolling a sequence 1,2,...,
6) is greater than or equal to: $(\prod_{i} p_{i}^{p_i})^{6/\sum_{i} p_i}$

What are the possible values
of p1, ..., p6 assuming they add up to 1?

What I tried?
I tried plugging in values for $i=[1, 6]$ to get 5 inequalities which are really complex to solve for.
For eg, $i=2$, $p_2^6 \ge (p_1^{p_1})^{6/p_1}. (p_2^{p_2})^{6/(p_1+p_2)}$

Comment: Just to be clear, is $$(\prod_{i} p_{i}^{p_i})^{6/\sum_{i} p_i}$$ intended to signify $$(\prod_{i=1}^6 p_{i}^{p_i})^{k},$$ where $$k = \frac{6}{\sum_{i=1}^6 p_i}?$$

Comment: It would help if you provided background on the problem.  Is this from a contest?  If so, which specific problem on which specific contest.  Alternatively, is this from a book or class?  If so, which one.  Under the assumption that you were assigned this problem, the book/class must have given you some preparation in the form of theorems or previously solved problems.  It would help if you shared this preparation.  Alternatively, is this an independent research question, outside of any class/book?

Comment: @user2661923 Yes that is correct

Comment: @user2661923 This is actually for a class. The text book is Probability: Theory and Examples by Rick Durrett. However the problem is not in the book

Comment: I realize that in this case, showing your work is going to be tedious and perhaps futile, from your perspective.  However, editing your query to show details on what you have tried so far will positively influence mathSE reviewers.  Personally, I am clueless how to even attack this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the background.  Did you make up the problem just out of curiosity, or did your teacher assign it?  If the latter, sharing the background of the problem in more detail will help, re theorems or previously solved problems you think might be pertinent.

Comment: Yes I am given this problem. I don't think there is any fancy theorems involved. The solution will be posted soon and I'll post it.

Comment: Isn't $\sum_{i=1}^6 p_i=1$ so that the exponent is just $6$?  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The probability of rolling $1,2,3,4,5,6$ is $\prod_{i=1}^6p_i$ so the condition becomes $1\geq\prod_{i=1}^6p_i^{6p_i-1}$ and it's true, for example if $p_i=\frac16,\ i=1,\dots,6$